# TS2339: Property does not exist on union type - property string | undefined

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0, union-types

I have problem with my union type, which looks like this:

```
type RepeatForm = {
    step:
        | {
              repeat: false;
          }
        | {
              repeat: true;
              from: undefined;
          }
        | {
              repeat: true;
              from: string;
              by?: string;
          };
};
```

And I have following function where I want to get value of `by` if it's there:

```
export const getByField = (form: RepeatForm) => {
    if (form.step.repeat === false || form.step.from === undefined) {
        return null;
    }
    const x = form.step.from;
    return form.step.by;
};
```

I get this error: `Property 'by' does not exist on type '{ repeat: true; from: undefined; } | { repeat: true; from: string; by?: string | undefined; }'.
  Property 'by' does not exist on type '{ repeat: true; from: undefined; }'.`

Which is super confusing for me, because TypeScript know that `form.step.from` is different from `undefined` and he even interpolates type of variable `x` to `string`.

What's the reason of this issue? How can I access `by` property then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163) for discriminated unions is very specific about the fact that the discriminating field must be a `string` literal type (with the option to add support for `boolean` and `number` literal types which seems to have happened). So your use case where you are discriminating based on the type of the field (`string` vs `undefined`) does not appear to be supported. This does not work for example:

```
let u!: { v: number, n: number } | { v: string, s: string}
if(typeof u.v === 'number') {
    u.n // not accesible, type not narrowed 
}
```

We could use conditional types and a custom type guard to make things work:

```
function isUndefined<T, K extends keyof T>(value : T, field: K) : value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : undefined }> {
    return !!value[field]
}

export const getByField = (form: RepeatForm) => {
    if (form.step.repeat === false || isUndefined(form.step, 'from')) {
        return null;
    }
    const x = form.step.from;
    return form.step.by;
};
```

We can also create a general version of this function that allows narrowing by any type:

```
type ExtractKeysOfType<T, TValue> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends TValue ? P : never}[keyof T]

function fieldOfType<T, K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, string>>(value : T, field: K, type: 'string'): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : string }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, number>>(value : T, field: K, type: 'number'): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : number }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, boolean>>(value : T, field: K, type: 'boolean'): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : boolean }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, Function>>(value : T, field: K, type: 'function'): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : Function }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, symbol>>(value : T, field: K, type: 'symbol'): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : symbol }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, object>>(value : T, field: K, type: 'object'): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : object }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, undefined>>(value : T, field: K, type: 'undefined'): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : undefined }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends keyof T, TValue extends T[K]>(value : T, field: K, type: new (...args:any[])=> TValue): value is Extract<T, { [P in K] : TValue }>
function fieldOfType<T, K extends keyof T>(value : T, field: K, type: string| Function) :boolean {
    if(typeof type === 'string') {
        return typeof value[field] === type;
    } else {
        return value[field] instanceof type
    }
}

const getByField = (form: RepeatForm) => {
    if (form.step.repeat === false || fieldOfType(form.step, 'from', 'undefined')) {
        return null;
    }
    const x = form.step.from;
    return form.step.by;
};


let u: { v: number, n: number } | { v: string, s: string}={ v: 0, n : 10};
if(fieldOfType(u, 'v', 'number')) {
    console.log(u.n);
}

class A {private a: undefined;}
class B {private b: undefined;}
let uc: { v: A, n: number } | { v: B, s: string} = Math.random() > 0.5 ? { v: new B(), s: '10' } : { v: new A(), n: 10 };
if(fieldOfType(uc, 'v', A)) {
    console.log(uc.n)
}
```

Comment: Do you know if TypeScript plans to support it?

Comment: @KonradKlimczak sorry I don't know of any plans to support this, but there may be an issue, seems like a common enough scenario.